# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name , on Oracle everything works fine

Tags: spring, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I  cannot figure out why I am getting "Invalid column name" here.

We have tried a variant of the SQL directly in Oracle, and it works fine, but when I try it using jdbcTemplate then something is wrong. (inside the @Query, The entire SQL that works on Oracle):

```
@Query(
        nativeQuery = true,
        value = "select a.ID,\n" +
        "  a.CREATION_DATE,\n" +
        "          a.SOURCE_,\n" +
        "          a.STATUS,\n" +
        "          a.PAYMENT_NUMBER2,\n" +
        "          a.PAYMENT_DATE,\n" +
        "          a.PAYMENT_AMOUNT,\n" +
        "          a.PAYERS_BIN,\n" +
        "          a.DESTINATION_ACCOUNT,\n" +
        "          a.ATTACHMENT_LINK,\n" +
        "          a.COMPANY_NAME,\n" +
        "          a.EMAIL,\n" +
        "          a.PHONE \n" +
        "          from APPLICATIONS partition for (date '2019-07-01') a\n" +
        "          where rownum between 0 and 100")
List<Application> findWithPartition();
```

The entire stacktrace:

```
    2019-07-11 13:57:56,272 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]] (http-nio-8090-exec-3) Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:4146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:300)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getLong(GeneratedResultSet.java:1361)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2738)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:118)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at kz.kcell.eregistry.service.application.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl.findAll(ApplicationServiceImpl.java:91)
    at kz.kcell.eregistry.service.application.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d8ebf7b0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at kz.kcell.eregistry.service.application.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f957d2ef.findAll(<generated>)
    at kz.kcell.eregistry.controller.ApplicationController.findAll(ApplicationController.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at kz.kcell.eregistry.config.CORSFilter.doFilterInternal(CORSFilter.java:19)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My Application object:

```cs
    Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "APPLICATIONS")
    @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"registries", "comments", "appFiles", "appErrors"})
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "APPLICATION_SEQ", sequenceName = "APPLICATION_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)

public class Application implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -841286587615540195L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "APPLICATION_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    //    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", timezone = "Asia/Almaty")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
    private Date creationDate;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "SOURCE_")
    private Source source;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private Status status;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_NUMBER2")
    private String paymentNumber; // the number of the payment order

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") // for REST operations (etc. ekassir search)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date paymentDate;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_AMOUNT")
    private Double paymentSum;

    @Column(name = "PAYERS_BIN")
    private String bin;

    @Column(name = "DESTINATION_ACCOUNT")
    private String destinationBankAccount; //In DataBase, column destinationBankAccount's bank name part wrapping with "»" signs is mandatory. For example АО «Банк ЦентрКредит» KZ 358560000000100922. It needs when bank information displays in different formats in several places.

    @Column(name = "ATTACHMENT_LINK")
    private String attachements;

    @Column(name = "COMPANY_NAME")
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "RESOLVER")
    private String resolver;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Transient
    private MultipartFile image;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "application",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Registry> registries;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "application",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AppFile> appFiles;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "application")
    private Set<Comment> comments;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "THIRD_PARTY_ID")
    private Long thirdPartyId;
    @Column(name = "DESTINATION_SAP_ACCOUNT")
    private Long destinationSapAccount;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "application",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AppError> appErrors;

    @JsonIgnore
    public Double getRegistriesPaymentSum() {
        final BigDecimal[] sum = {BigDecimal.valueOf(0)};
        registries.forEach(registry ->
                sum[0] = sum[0].add(BigDecimal.valueOf(registry.getAmount())));
        BigDecimal result = sum[0].setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);

        return result.doubleValue();
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<String> getMsisdnsFromRegistry() {
        List<String> msisdns = new ArrayList<>();
        registries.forEach(registry -> msisdns.add(registry.getMsisdn()));

        return msisdns;
    }

    public Application(Long id, Date creationDate, Status status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Application{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", companyName=" + companyName +
                ", creationDate=" + creationDate +
                ", source=" + source +
                ", paymentNumber=" + paymentNumber +
                ", paymentDate=" + paymentDate +
                ", paymentSum=" + paymentSum +
                ", status=" + status +
                ", bin=" + bin +
                ", destinationBankAccount='" + destinationBankAccount + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: remove `\n` in your SQL query

Comment: The column name in the query reads `DESTINATION_ACCOUNT`. The column in your entity is declared as `DESTINATION_SAP_ACCOUNT`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: \n and he column name in the query reads DESTINATION_ACCOUNT wasnt solve my problem. Is might be problem that Im querying not enough parameter to Object Application. Because Im querying getting just set of parameters not all? Should I create new View with parameter that I need to my get query

Comment: I wonder if `rownum` (an Oracle virtual column) is not being handled by your JDBC driver; I would try to use Oracles' `ojdbc7.jar` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do this, try to add `as` statement to your select. Like

```
@Query(
            nativeQuery = true,
            value = "select a.ID as ID," +
                    "  a.CREATION_DATE as CREATION_DATE," +
                    "          a.SOURCE_ as SOURCE_," +
                    "          a.STATUS as STATUS," +
                    "          a.PAYMENT_NUMBER2 as PAYMENT_NUMBER2," +
                    "          a.PAYMENT_DATE as PAYMENT_DATE," +
                    "          a.PAYMENT_AMOUNT as PAYMENT_AMOUNT," +
                    "          a.PAYERS_BIN as PAYERS_BIN," +
                    "          a.DESTINATION_ACCOUNT as DESTINATION_ACCOUNT," +
                    "          a.ATTACHMENT_LINK as ATTACHMENT_LINK," +
                    "          a.COMPANY_NAME as COMPANY_NAME," +
                    "          a.EMAIL as EMAIL," +
                    "          a.PHONE  as PHONE " +
                    "          from APPLICATIONS partition for (date '2019-07-01') a" +
                    "          where rownum between 0 and 100")
    List<Application> findWithPartition();
```